# Request access to a facebook Page using facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, api

how to request access to a facebook Page for business account using facebook marketing api

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Facebook API documentation, or tried asking in their forums?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook released a special website dedicated to the Marketing API:

https://www.facebookmarketingdevelopers.com/reference_app/

You can watch theses videos as well to understand how it works:

https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos